# Cannot find symbol error while compiling java class from the command line

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I want to compile a java class called `Contrat.java` which is using an object of the class `ListContrat.java` both classes are located in the same folder whose path is : `C:\Users\hue7\workspace\Test\src\com\sky`, I tried to compile (create .class) executing the following commands from the folder namded sky:

`javac Contrat.java` and `javac -cp ListContrat.java Contrat.java` both gives the error:

```
    Contrat.java:21: error: cannot find symbol 
        protected List<ListContrat> contrat; 
                       ^ 
  symbol:   class ListContrat 
  location: class Contrat 
Contrat.java:23: error: cannot find symbol 
        public List<ListContrat> getContrat() { 
                    ^ 
  symbol:   class ListContrat 
  location: class Contrat 
Note: Contrat.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 
2 errors
```

But when I execute the command `javac Contrat.java` from `src` folder it works correctly.

Can anyone explain why please ?

Comment: From oracle, how to set a classpath https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the error, executing the command from the `src` folder.